# Is there a fast way to inverse a quasi-diagonal matrix in Eigen?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I want to inverse a quasi-diagonal matrix with Eigen, of course I can use inverse(), but I wonder if inverse() will check if the matrix if (quasi)diagonal. Is there a faster function to do this?

Comment: By "quasi-diagonal" do you mean block-diagonal? There is no built-in solution for this in Eigen, especially `inverse()` will not analyze the non-zero structure of the matrix it has to invert (it will always use a partial pivoting LU decomposition).

Comment: yes, I mean block-diagonal. if there is no build-in inverse() for this, I wonder if it will be faster if I write one myself, the blocks in my block-diagonal matrix are all 3x3.

Comment: To answer my own question, I tried this with 81*81 matrix, every 2*2 block-diagonal, it is 10 times faster with my own blockly-inverse method